# Libgdx Sound occasionally occurs twice

Tags: java, android, audio, libgdx

When playing a `Sound` in Android with Libgdx, the sound occasionally occurs twice. It plays twice when the game is first loaded or when it doesn't play for ~5 seconds. So for instance, don't play the sound and wait for 5 seconds, then play the sound. The sound fires off twice instead of only once.

I created a simple app to demonstrate this. On button click, it should play the sound once. However, as noted above, there are times when it occurs twice. Here is a video demonstrating it - https://youtu.be/Zi0xutH_8yc. The first time it plays the "click" sound twice when it should play it only once. Then I click two more times and get two click sounds, which is correct. Then I pause for a few seconds and click again which results incorrectly in two "click" sounds.

Source code:

```
package com.soundtest.example;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.audio.Sound;

public class SoundExample extends ApplicationAdapter {

    @Override
    public void create () {

        final Sound clickSound = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("click.ogg"));

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("Clicked!");
                clickSound.play();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I've tried different audio formats, different sound files, and making the sound longer by adding silence to the end of the file, but still the same issue occurs. I also tried the `AsynchronousAndroidAudio` but that didn't work either.

```
@Override
public AndroidAudio createAudio(Context context, AndroidApplicationConfiguration config) {
    return new AsynchronousAndroidAudio(context, config);
}
```

How can I get it to correctly only play the sound file once? Here is a link to download the audio file - https://gofile.io/d/XeP5zN

Comment: @londonBadger, I've essentially done that with the print statements.

Comment: what libgdx version are you on?

Comment: @Naruto26 `1.12.0` but also tried with `1.10.0`

Comment: might be an issue with emulator? can u try it on an actual physical device